# unusual remainder on float by int

Tags: python-2.7

I was trying to find remainder for a `float`,

```
>>> x = 123.1233

>>> x%1
0.12330000000000041
```

The remainder should be `0.1233` but where is this extra `0000000000041` coming from, have faced this before too but don't know, what is causing this.